# Print the contents of a hash in insertion order

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have the following script

```
my %hash = (
             'ev2'  => 'aaaa',
             'ev1' => 'bbbb'
           );   

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
   print $key , '-' , $hash{$key},  "\n";
}
```

that prints

```
ev1 - bbbb
ev2 - aaaa
```

I want to print the elements in the order they were added to the hash.

```
ev2 - aaaa  
ev1 - bbbb
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I want to sort it as it is in my declaration of the hash variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash does not record the order in which elements are added to it, so you can't achieve what you want with just a hash.

You could use [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::IxHash) to provide something that looks like a hash, but preserves insertion order.

```
use Tie::IxHash qw( );

tie my %hash, Tie::IxHash => (
    ev2 => 'aaaa',
    ev1 => 'bbbb',
);   

for my $key ( keys(%hash) ) {
    my $val = $hash{$key};
    ...
}
```

There will be a performance penalty for using Tie::IxHash or similar modules.

---

If you don't need to access arbitrary elements, it would be much faster to simply use an array.

```
use List::Util qw( pairs );    # 1.29+

my @pairs = (
    ev2 => 'aaaa',
    ev1 => 'bbbb',
);   

for (pairs(@pairs)) {
    my ($key, $val) = @$_;
    ...
}
```

or

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@pairs; ) {
    my $key = $pairs[$i++];
    my $val = $pairs[$i++];
    ...
}
```

Comment: neither by the key  nor by the value. I want to sort it as it is in the declaration of the hash variable

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the key/value pairs in the list you use to initialize the hash variable is not preserved; by the time the hash variable is populated, that ordering is long gone.

To preserve the order in which the keys were originally added to the hash - which includes the order of any list used to initialize it - you can use the CPAN module [`Hash::Ordered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered).

It has a `tie` interface, so you can use a `Hash::Ordered` object as if it were a plain hash. Note that you don't need to quote keys on the left side of `=>` if they're simple words:

```
use Hash::Ordered;

tie my %hash, Hash::Ordered => (
             ev2 => 'aaaa',
             ev1 => 'bbbb'
           );

while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
  print "$key - $value\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ev2 - aaaa
ev1 - bbbb
```

You could also do the loop as in your original code, just without the `sort`:

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  print "$key - $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

But using `each` saves a hash lookup for each item and returns them in the same order as `keys`.

@duskwuff suggested `Hash::Ordered` first; I just supplied some sample code. @ikegami suggested the older module `Tie::IxHash`. Both work for this purpose, and neither comes standard with Perl; you need to install them from the CPAN (e.g. with the `cpan` or `cpanm` commands).

Answer (score 1):

You can't, exactly. Hashes do not have a "natural" order -- the order that elements were assigned is not recorded.

If you really want an ordered hash, use [`Hash::Ordered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered). Or an array.

Comment: Since it sounds like this is what OP wants, maybe add some sample code using `Hash::Ordered`.

Comment: Yes, could you provide some more code please

Comment: @Paramore Have you taken a look at the documentation for the module? There is an overview in the "SYNOPSIS" section.